# NodeJs hosting .html fails with ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to serve an HTML file with express. This is my code here, and it works perfectly locally:

```
var express = require('express');

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname + '/test.html'), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.send(data)
        }
    });
});
```

But when I deploy this on the node server that my customer is using, I get an ENOENT.

```
{
 fault: {
  faultstring: "Script executed prematurely: ENOENT",
  detail: {
     errorcode: "messaging.runtime.ScriptExitedError"
  }
}
```

I am using the relative path `__dirname + '/test.html'`. So what am I missing?
console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/testFileUpload.html')) shows up the right path locally.
but when deployed, the path goes haywire.

Comment: The file doesn’t exist there. So did you put it there? If you did, where is it? Where’s your server?

Comment: BTW: You should never concatenate paths using `+`. Use `path.join` instead. It will take care of `/` and `\`` correctly (for Windows), and handle multiple `/` in a path well.

Comment: (Windows deals fine with `/` on its own, for what it’s worth.)

Comment: Its just a basic HTML form.  Its on the same level as app.js.

Comment: Then try `path.join` on them. Or `console.log(__dirname + '/test.html');` to find out.

Comment: path.join didnt help. See edits